# Can we inherit from a record but have a new attribute name

Tags: c#, xml

Let's say my base is like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "meow")]
public record MyBaseRecord { // yada yada }
```

Now can I have a record inherting from that one **but** I want it to have a new attribute name so like this: **Note** that I don't want it to end up having TWO attributes . I only want the `CuteKitten` attribute.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CuteKitten")]
public record BabyKittenRecord : MyBaseRecord { // tuna methods }
```

Comment: I must be missing something. I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: yeah I wasn't sure if I can or not.  Because of the attribute. I don't want the new class to have BOTH attributes. I want it to have only the "CuteKitten"  attrbiute.

Comment: Why don't you ... try it out? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen too tired ! My back hurts and I am hungry and also very very sleepy.

Comment: Go do something about that then, it'll probably make software development easier ;-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, It's Friday , I am out of here. See you Monday . Byeeeee